# How to remove row from gridview on row command event?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I am trying to remove row from gridview by click on ImageButton which is placed inside gridview. I am getting row index but dont know how to remove. My gridview binds from session and i dont want to rebind gridview.

Here is my code:

```
protected void GVDetail_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("Remove"))
    {
      List<Class1> list = (List<Class1>)Session["value1"];
      int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
      GridViewRow gridRow = gvDetail.Rows[index];// (GridViewRow)(((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

      ((List<Class1>)Session["value1"]).RemoveAt(index);
    }
  }
```

If anyone have any idea about this than please help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the gridview deleterow method.

```
void GVDetail_RowCommand_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
if(e.CommandName=="Remove")
{
     var id = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument);
     GVDetail.DeleteRow(id);

 }
}
```

Comment: have you bind the grid after removing ? call the gridview.Bind() method after deleting.

Comment: you have to call the bind method bcz otherwise gridview will not update.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13862/discussion-between-user968441-and-waqar-janjua)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GVPurchaseOrderTax_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dt.Rows[e.RowIndex].Delete();
            GVPurchaseOrderTax.DataSource = dt;
            GVPurchaseOrderTax.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```