# How to delete one row in GridView with DropDownList in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my design page

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"     Inherits="newsamplecomb._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true"   AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px"
        CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2"    OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1"
        Height="246px" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" Width="1017px">
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Rollno<br />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="23px"    Width="73px" 
                        AutoPostBack="True" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Name
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="155px"    ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    English<br />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="17px" Width="103px"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Tamil<br />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="103px"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Maths
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="103px"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Science
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="103px"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Total<br />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="103px"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Grade
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="103px"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click1" Text="+" />
                    <asp:Button ID="Buttondel" runat="server" Text="Del"></asp:Button>
                   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv" runat="server" ErrorMessage="" ForeColor="White" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Width="10" Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:GridView>

</div>
<%-- //<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"        ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ForeColor="White" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Width="10"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%>
```

This is my cs code

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");
            string connection_string = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBC"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection_string);
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from stud_table", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            da.Fill(ds);
            //  con.Close();
            ddl.DataSource = ds;
            ddl.DataTextField = "Rollno";
            ddl.DataValueField = "Rollno";
            ddl.DataBind();
            ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
        }
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dpditemdesc( sender,e);
        DropDownList box1 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[x].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");

        if (box1.Text != "")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Enabled = false;
                GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Enabled = false;
                GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Enabled = false;
                GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Enabled = false;
                GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Enabled = false;
                GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Enabled = false;
                GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Enabled = true;
                GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Enabled = true;
                GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Enabled = true;
                GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Enabled = true;
                GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Enabled = true;
                GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Enabled = true;
                GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
    public void dpditemdesc(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;
        x = row.RowIndex;
        TextBox box = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[x].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox1");
        if (box.Text == "")
        {
            try
            {
                x = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ct"].ToString());
                x++;
                Session["ct"] = x.ToString();
            }
            catch
            {
                x = 0;
                Session["ct"] = x.ToString();
            }
        }
        if (ddl.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
        string connection_string =     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBC"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection_string);

        DropDownList box1 =                                 (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[x].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
        TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[x].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox1");
        TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[x].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox2");
        TextBox box4 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[x].Cells[4].FindControl("TextBox3");
        TextBox box5 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[x].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox4");
        TextBox box6 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[x].Cells[6].FindControl("TextBox5");
        TextBox box7 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[x].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox6");
        TextBox box8 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[x].Cells[8].FindControl("TextBox7");


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from stud_table where Rollno='" + box1.Text + "'", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            box2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
            box3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();
            box4.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString();
            box5.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString();
            box6.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][5].ToString();
            box7.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][6].ToString();
            box8.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][7].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            // box.Text = "";
            Response.Write("<Script>alert('Please Select Item Description')</script>");
        }

    }
}
}
```

I want to select one row and, if I click delete button, the selected row should be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for showing your code!  However, I don't see any attempt to do this delete operation in there.  What have you tried so far?  What about your approach didn't work?  If you haven't tried anything, there are plenty of examples of deleting from a GridView here on Stack Overflow, and other places on the Internet.

Comment: i think you should use grid view row command event and pass command argument and command Name property to Buttons.....

Comment: i tried that but first i want to select the row after selecting i want to delete by using button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link

[How to remove row from gridview on row command event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473226/how-to-remove-row-from-gridview-on-row-command-event)

Use gridview rowcommand as Rajpurohit said, then use `gvYourGrid.DeleteRow(index);`

Comment: i cant understand because am new to asp..