# C# gridview how to remove index

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

hey guys i was wondering how do i remove a item that has been inserted into a list a view

been actually searching the net for some time and can not find something that is useful.

here is my code i wanna be able to remove what i have added via the list thank you.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    List<Book> list = (List<Book>)Session["SelectedBooks"];
    if (list != null)
    {
      GridViewProducts.DataSource = list;
      GridViewProducts.DataBind();
    }
    //list of borrows
  }
}

protected void GridViewProducts_RowCommand(object sender, 
                                                     GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    if (e.CommandName == "Remove")
    {
      GridViewProducts.DeleteRow(GridViewProducts.SelectedIndex);    
    }
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    lblInfo.Text = "Can not remove selected book from Bag.";           
  }
}
```

Comment: still does not work unless i am putting it in the wrong place i've been coding all day. So foggy been stuck for like 2 hours?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11473365/900284

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Add `CommandName` to the delete button inside Gridview markup:

```
<asp:Button Text="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />
```

Handle the `RowDeleting` event, remove the item from the datasource, then rebind the gridview. Modify your source code like this:

```
private List<Book> SelectedBooks
{
    get
    {
        return Session["SelectedBooks"] as List<Book>;
    }
    set
    {
        Session["SelectedBooks"] = value;
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {       
        var selectedBooks = SelectedBooks;
        if(selectedBooks == null)
        {
            // Populate the selected books first time
            // SelectedBooks = ...
        }

        BindGridview(SelectedBooks);
    }
}

private void BindGridview(List<Book> bookList)
{   
    GridViewProducts.DataSource = bookList;
    GridViewProducts.DataBind();
}

protected void GridViewProducts_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{      
    SelectedBooks.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);         
    BindGridview(SelectedBooks);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DataKey attribute to bind some primarykey of the opensource to gridview  and in row command use this datakey to remove the item from data source and than rebind the grid with the modified data source.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove item from collection and rebind (as said in other answers)

But I see that `List<Book> list` is declared locally in Page_Load method. So how are you trying to achieve this?