# Gridview doesn't refresh after deleting a row

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a `GridView` in an `UpdatePanel`.

When I add a row, it gets updated right away. The problem is that, when I delete a row, it doesn't update the `GridView`.

What can be done?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["EventId"] != null)
        {
            ExtractEventData();
            GridView1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
        }
    }
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string CS = 
       ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ss"].ConnectionString;
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
     {
         con.Open();
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spInsertComment", con);
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", txtComment.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Eventid", lblEventId.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", Session["UserId"].ToString());
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         txtComment.Text = "";
         GridView1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
         GridView1.DataBind();
     }
}

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        int id = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ss"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
              "Delete from tblEventComments WHERE CommentId = @CommentId", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CommentId", id);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            GridView1.DataSourceID = "";
            GridView1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried removing the `datasource1` connection from `GridView` and then re-assigned it. Still it doesn't seem to work, the way I need it to.

I don't think you will need the `GridView` markup here, however you can ask for it if necessary.

Comment: I have gone through that link already.Nothing seems to work.There are no datatables in my code as you can see

Comment: Are you sure that `ExecuteNonQuery` returns `> 0`? Maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Did you try to `databind()` the DataSource following the SQL deletion?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11473365/75500) post, you should delete the row using [`GridView.DeleteRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.deleterow) method.

Comment: I am afraid im not looking for an alternative method to delete the row.I just want to refresh my gridview or just refresh the connection between sqldatasource to gridview