# Remove GridView deleted row data from gridview directly

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is code for delete row:

```
    else if (e.CommandName == "Deleterow")
                {
                    GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)
((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;      
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure4", con);
                    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", gr.Cells[0].Text);
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }
```

aspx:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
        if (e.CommandName == "EditRow")
        {
            GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;               
            Textid.Text = gr.Cells[0].Text;
            Textusername.Text = gr.Cells[1].Text;
            Textclass.Text = gr.Cells[2].Text;
            Textsection.Text = gr.Cells[3].Text;
            Textaddress.Text = gr.Cells[4].Text;
        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "Deleterow")
        {
            GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;      
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure4", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", gr.Cells[0].Text);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
```

When i delete the button, It removed data row after reload the page.

So i need to remove the row directly from the gridview.

For that what to do, can anyone help?

Thanks,

Comment: No need to reload page just rebind your grid after com.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Instead of using `Response.Redirect()` rebind your gridview

Comment: @Rani: Do you your **Page_Load** content. That will be more easy for us to give you proper solution.

Comment: Ok, Just share the portion where you are populating the gridview for e.g. `GridView1.Datasource` is being called.

Comment: may `GridView1.DeleteRow(gr.Cells[0].Text);` will resolve your issue.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473226/how-to-remove-row-from-gridview-on-row-command-event

Comment: hi, it shows error something , here is the screenshot http://s10.postimg.org/fltaptmmh/untitled.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
            else if (e.CommandName == "Deleterow")
            {
                GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)
                ((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;      
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure4", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", gr.Cells[0].Text);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //Response.Redirect("studententry.aspx"); Remove this line
                //call method here you have used to populate the gridview at page load.  
            }
```

Comment: this line in your answer,  Rebind grid here.?

Comment: The method you have used to populate the gridview at page load call that method

Comment: @Rani, How to bind gridview first time  ?

Comment: you said in your answer, call method here you have used to populate the gridview at page load.  .but i don't have code in page_load..

Comment: @Rani, ok. but which method to use for bind gridview. same code put on there.

Comment: @Rani, How to bind Grid view on first time?